# Is there a way to add more than one property to a particular XML ELement usng c#'s XMLWrite?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlwriter

I am trying to programatically add elements using c#'s XML writer and everything is working great. I currently have this:

```
<module_name path="pathToModule"></module_name>
```

I am trying to attain a structure like so:

```
<module_name path="pathToModule" name="nameOfModule", executable="moduleExecutale"></module_name>
```

My XMLWriter looks something like this:

```
var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
   Indent = true,
   IndentChars = "\t",
   NewLineOnAttributes = true
};
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(_pathToOutputXml, xmlWriterSettings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("module_name", "name", realModuleName);

}
```

I have also tried

```
writer.WriteStartElement("module_name", "name", realModuleName);
writer.WriteAttributeString("path", path, "executable", executable);
```

and it doesn't compile past this. There is an error Invalid name character in 'file'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value, cannot be included in a name. I imagine this is the wrong approach but I do not see another option.

What XMLWriter properties can I use to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why restrict to `XMLWriter`, not `XmlDocument`or `XDocuemnt`?

Comment: What is it about that structure that you specifically want? The list of attributes? The blank line? The full end element `</modulename>`? The malformed `,` separating the attributes? Also the given code produces nothing like what you say you've got, so that adds to the confusion.

Comment: @LeiYang I am not restricted to XMLWriter, its just what I have been using to programmatically create an XML Document.

Comment: @mikez Sorry for the confusion but all I am seeking is multiple attributes like so <module_name path="pathToModule" name="nameOfModule", executable="moduleExecutale">

Comment: I am not sure XMLWriter provides this functionality?

Comment: Then suggest you try `XmlDocument` or `XDocuemnt`

Comment: @LeiYang XmlDocumentor?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: try `WriteAttributeString`

Comment: @mikez That didn't work. Ideally I would like a method where there is a large number of key/value attribute pairs.

Comment: @jshaf Well I might be able to help if I knew what you tried and what went wrong, but all I know now is that it "didn't work". There's no such method. The intention is that you call WriteAttributeString for each attribute. Feel free to write a wrapper method if you so desire.

Comment: @mikez I updated the question with the issue. It doesn't seem like XmlWriter has a method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out that if I want to add attributes to a certain Element I would need to do something like this:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("module_name");
writer.WriteAttributeString("name", realModuleName);
writer.WriteAttributeString("path", path); 
writer.WriteAttributeString("executable", executable);
```

This would result in an element like this:

```
<module_name name="Captiva Administrator" path="" executable="test.exe">
```